# Is electron/photon wave or particle in Feynman sum over histories formulation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, quantum-interpretations, wave-particle-duality

In the famous double slit experiment, a photon (say) can behave as wave or particle depending on whether there is (or how) an outside observer measuring the experiment.

Copenhagen interpretation interpret this wave-particle duality by saying that the photon behaves as wave when unobserved, and the act of interpretation "collapses" the wave function makes it behaves as particle.

How would Feynman sum over histories formulation interpret this duality? Or to put it the other way, how does Feynman sum over histories interpret Quantum decoherence? Or it is ***just*** a mathematical tool, nothing more, so it doesn't really care about whether a photon is a wave or particle and *there is no underlying QM interpretation*?

Comment: How much QM have you taken? You won't get satisfactory answers to these kinds of broad questions until late into a QM course or even early into a QFT course.

Comment: A photon is an irreversible energy exchange between the electromagnetic field and an external system. It never behaves like either a particle or a wave. It is merely an amount of energy that flows from one system to another. I would suggest that you forget everything that you have heard about wave-particle duality. Dirac already made the point in the 1930s that quantum systems have to be treated as a completely new class of phenomenon that is neither a classical wave nor a classical particle. It's strange that this insight is still not universally known... almost 100 years later.

Comment: Saying quantum systems are "neither a classical wave nor a classical particle" is just as silly as claiming wave-particle duality. Either one is a cop-out.

Answer (score 1):

The sum over histories formulation is the path [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) method:

> The path integral formulation of quantum mechanics is a description of quantum theory that generalizes the action principle of classical mechanics. It replaces the classical notion of a single, unique classical trajectory for a system with a sum, or functional integral, over an infinity of quantum-mechanically possible trajectories to compute a quantum amplitude.

Thus it is a way of calculating that is mathematically equivalent to the others:

> The path-integral approach has been proved to be equivalent to the other formalisms of quantum mechanics and quantum field theory. Thus, by deriving either approach from the other, problems associated with one or the other approach (as exemplified by Lorentz covariance or unitarity) go away.

The particles in the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) are particles in the sense that when measured they have a unique mass and the quantum numbers identifying them in the table. The wave nature appears in the **probability distributions** for the given interactions, as with the double slit experiment.

So yes, it is a mathematical tool equivalent to the others used in quantum mechanical calculations.

Comment: So, it is "a mathematical tool equivalent to the others"-- and nothing more? So it also doesn't' shed any lights on the QM interpretation?

Comment: the "more" comes from the ease of formulating the mathematics for specific calculations, as you will see if you read the link further. you can think of it as another mathematical interpretation.

Comment: there is this review https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811023

Comment: It is equivalent, but that does not mean that it doesn't shed light on interpretation.  When taken together with other formalisms, it sheds light on the fact that whatever picture we hold in our (too human) brain has to be wrong.